# htaccess mod-rewrite language overrides

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using some mod-rewrite code in my sites .htaccess file to redirect users with browser languages set to various languages to different versions of my site. This is working well - but... I need a way to be able to override these rewrite rules when a user wants to view the main English version instead of the version they would get automatically redirected to based on the language setting of their browser.

So for example, user A has their browser language set to Korean, they visit the example.com site - the rewrite rules reads they are set to Korean and moves them to example.co.kr - on example.co.kr I have a button which says - Show me the English version of this website (which links to example.com) - this then links back to example.com... but currently then redirects back to example.co.kr as the rewrite script refires...

How can I code the rewrite script to allow for an overwrite rule to force it to stay on the example.com site when I want it too...?

rewrite code I have is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
#RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ko [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.co.kr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/br/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt-PT [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/br/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt-BR [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/br/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(|ko|pt|pt-PT|pt-BR)/?$ https://example.com/ [QSA,NC,L]
```

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Comment: add a parameter to the query and check that in your rewrite rules. Use the query parameter over the Accept-Language header and voila.

Comment: Thanks @Murf - any chance of a code suggestion / link - htaccess code is new to me // thanks

Comment: Anyone any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: When user clicks on **Show me the English version of this website** what link does it send to server?

Comment: @anubhava - https://example.com is the url to view the English version

Comment: Can you add a special query parameter like `force=1` when user is clicking on any `show me abc version of this website` ?

Comment: @anubhava - yes - in theory - but i dont know what the syntax / code is to do that - could you give me an example to work from? Easily make the button on the Back to English version of this site url have a ?notKO string added to the url yes - how do I detect that in the .htaccess to make it not fire the rewrite back to the example.co.kr site?

Comment: Anyone any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your rules to look for a special query parameter e.g. `notKO` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !notKO [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !notKO [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^ko [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.co.kr/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !notKO [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/br/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !notKO [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt-PT [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/br/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !notKO [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^pt-BR [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/br/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(|ko|pt|pt-PT|pt-BR)/?$ / [NC,L]
```

Now you need to start sending `?notKO` query parameter on your `show me abc version of this website` button click.

Clear your browser before you test this change.